# Fill out grid, then extend downwards in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

[enter image description here][1]I want to make an application that shows all files in a folder as buttons, so I can open them from the application. So they are getting added dynamically. But I have a problem: I need to show them like a grid, side by side. And if there are more than 9 files it needs to scroll down. I have tried with the layout:

```
<Grid Name="buttonGrid">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid Height="450" Width="800" Background="White">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And I C#:

```
public partial class PlayGame : Page
{
    public PlayGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddButtons();

    }

    //Add buttons to grid
    private void AddButtons()
    {
        var folderName = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}games";
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
        }

        var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderName);

        foreach (string fileName in allFiles)
        {
            var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);


            Button newBtn = new Button
            {
                Content = fi.Name,
                Name = "Button" + fi.Name.Replace(".", "_"),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(0)
            };

            Grid.SetRow(newBtn, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(newBtn, 0);

            newBtn.Click += OpenFile;

            buttonGrid.Children.Add(newBtn);

        }
    }
}
```

And it works partly... The buttons are getting added, and they work, but they are stacked on each other. So how would i fix that?

I want it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EUKS.png
But dynamically for each file, there is in a folder. And if there are more than 9 files extend downwards so the scrollviewer comes into action.

Comment: Can you please explain better what you want to obtain? Add an immage if possible

Comment: Use <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> if I understood what did you mean

Comment: <ScrollViewer Height="300">
            <WrapPanel Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal">
            </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer> if you need scroll

Comment: I got it working with a WrapPanel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
<ScrollViewer Height="300">
    <WrapPanel Name="listView" Orientation="Horizontal">
    </WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about a WrapPanel!

Comment: you are wellcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Your very close.
Try increasing the column

```
Grid.SetColumn(newBtn, i);
```

for every iteration.

Then you can also set the row

```
Grid.SetRow(newBtn, i % 3);
```

to add a new row every three buttons.

Now if you want a new row you can add it with this command:

```
buttonGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to extend if it's more than 9 files. Because else all the files are in one place. How would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by extend? Should it add new rows?